# OpenAPI 3 Links. What are they good for?

Tags: hyperlink, openapi

I have spent a lot of time trying to figure out what OpenAPI Links can be used for and how they relate to hypermedia links in the body of a response & it's doing my head in!
Lets say the simple class model below represents the business domain for which we have defined an OpenAPI spec that provides paths to navigate the instances of the various classes.

[image: Example Class Diagram]

For example, if I perform a get of /borrowers/{id}, I would expect the response to contain both the properties of Borrower and a means to follow R1 or R2 to get the relevant set of Book instances.
Before OpenAPI 3 I would have constructed links to the relevant paths e.g.
/borrowers/{id}/loaned-books or /borrowers/{id}/reserved-books and included those as properties (hyperlinks) in the definition of the response body.
At runtime, if I followed those hyperlinks I would get an array of the relevant Books each of which had other hyperlinks. 
So the OpenAPI Link questions are:

1. Are they a replacement for the need to generate hyperlinks in the response? I don't think so but in which case
2. What is the Runtime Expression Language (REL) for?
3. Are they just a means of defining hyperlinks in the API spec? Possibly but in which case does the response body definition still need to include properties for those links? Presumably their values still need to have the actual hyperlinks created on the server?
4. Given that the REL doesn't allow wildcards how do you define links when the response is an array of resources, each of which has an id to be used by the next operation? 
   Any help explaining links would be gratefully received.

Comment: Check out https://swagger.io/docs/specification/links/, it should answer at least some of your questions.

Comment: Thanks but I have spent a long time looking at that document and it does not help. The examples are trivial and the whole concept seems inconsistent. Hence the questions.

Answer (score 1):

It's bit old question but may be its useful for someone. 
The possible one use case which I use everyday is "testing" your endpoints using openapi. I'm using [schemathesis](https://github.com/schemathesis/schemathesis) which automatically test endpoints, but problem arises when there is no links in following scenario. 
for example, I have created a new record using POST request /users which creates a record but now if I want to do a get request using specific id such as /users/{userId}, I can not do that test independently. I need to link these two.

that's where [schemathesis stateful](https://schemathesis.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stateful.html) option can be used but only if your openapi has links.
I will copy paste the specific snippet from schemathesis page inn case it gets modified

```
  paths:
   /users:
     post:
       summary: Creates a user and returns the user ID
       operationId: createUser
       requestBody:
         required: true
         description: User object
         content:
           application/json:
             schema:
               $ref: '#/components/schemas/User'
       responses:
         '201':
           ...
           links:
             GetUserByUserId:
               operationId: getUser  # The target operation
               parameters:
                 userId: '$response.body#/id'
   /users/{userId}:
     get:
       summary: Gets a user by ID
       operationId: getUser
       parameters:
         - in: path
           name: userId
           required: true
           schema:
             type: integer
             format: int64
```

Hope that this helps.